# Why are values copied from returned grid marked with quotes?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In PgAdmin III, when I copy value from returned grid and paste it into the query text, it appears there in double quotes. But to use it in query, in where clause for example, it has to be marked with apostrophe. So I have to replace quotes with apostrophe. It is rather weird for me that I always have to do so. Why it is designed in such strange way?
This is a kind of stupid theoretical question, I do not expect any practical answers :)

Comment: When you say "PostgreSQL" ... do you mean "PgAdmin-III"? `psql` in `cmd.exe` on Windows or `Terminal.app` on Mac or an xterm on *nix? Something else? PostgreSQL version? Please show the actual query you're talking about and the unexpected results.

Comment: Like when I execute `select * from pg_stat_all_indexes` and copy-paste schemaname value, it appears like `"public"`. But if I want to use this value in where clause for example i have to use it like `'public'`. I'm talking about pgAdmin-III

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour. PgAdmin-III version? Platform (Mac, Windows, Linux, ...) ? Can you give a step-by-step description of the issue?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can customize the quoting character, by following the following steps.

1. On the PgAdmin-III main window, click on File and then Options
2. Click on the Query Tool Tab
3. Change the field called "Result copy quote character" to apostrophe (')

It should work, you may need to close and open PgAdmin-III

**EDIT:** For Mac OS X the option could be found in pgAdmin3 > Preferences > Query tool > Results grid

Answer (score 9):

For pgAdmin 4 go to File> Preferences> SQL Editor> Results Grid. You can change the Quotation mark to single quote or none.

Comment: Result copy quoting ==> none

Comment: Had to restart pgAdmin for this to take effect (pgAdmin 4, version 7.7)